# django python datetime naive and aware

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

Im working with django and a some python code, but now i get the TypeError:can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Now i guess that django uses Europe/Amsterdam timezone and i don't think i use one with python.

```
class SkillTrainingTimer(models.Model):
    character = models.ForeignKey(Character, unique=True)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, blank=True)
    trainingground = models.ForeignKey(TrainingGround)
    timer = models.DateTimeField()


    def time_remaining(self):
        remaining = datetime.datetime.now() - self.timer

        return remaining
```

how can i add the timezone using python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects)

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

def time_remaining(self):
    remaining = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc) - self.timer

    return remaining
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew i found it somewhere, couldnt find it again :)